# How to read specyfic record from custom database on Firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Problem:

I try read everything from specific record

Everything is:

```
database.child("Youtube1");
```

[image]

Now I need to pick data from `Information` and put ir into `TextView`

Link to Intent

Text to Text View

(I know how to put it in, but I don't know how to get the response from server)

The method that I know is `ValueEventListener`

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
```

Of course I initialize the database with:

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

I try do in `ValueEventListener` like

```
settingsText3.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube1").child("Information").getValue(String.class));
```

But this not work, here is my case for VIDE TUTORIALS

```
case VIDEO_TUTORIALS:
            settingsText3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    settingsText3.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube1").child("Information").getValue(String.class));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };

            break;
```

Any advice will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `mDatabase` in one place and `valueEventListener` in another place, so those two are not connected. You should connect both object, like this (place it after initialization of both):

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Or directly attach new listener into `mDatabase`, like this: (if you use this, remove your initialization of `valueEventListener` as it is not needed anymore):

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        settingsText3.setText(...); // place your code here
    ...
...
```

You can use one of that. Hope this helps